# Input from image doesnt load until i refresh the page (angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, angular5

Im uploading pictures and i need them to display without reloading the page

```
   .subscribe(res => {
          if(this.newFamMember.imageFile) {
            res.Id;
            let data = {
              Entity: 'Patient',
              Id: res.Id,
              Images: [
                {
                  FileName: this.newFamMember.imageFile.name,
                  EntityType: 'ImagePath'
                }
              ]
            };
            let dataArr = [data];
            this.patientService.addImage(dataArr, [this.newFamMember.imageFile]);
          }

          this.currentUserData.familyMembers.push(this.patient1);
          this.alerts.showSuccess("Cambios guardados con éxito", '', 3);
      },
```

its all working fine just that it doesnt show on upload and needs a page refresh
Im sure its something simple but i cant find the answer on Stack overflow

Comment: a bit more description and code would be helpfull

Comment: what code would you like to see buddy. i dont know what more of a description you need. its working perfectly outside of the page needing to be refreshed

Comment: i realise the problem i have image path set to empty to avoid the fakepath error. is there a way to set the image and avoid this error